# How do I do a summation in C without math.c?

Tags: c

Hello I need to create this summation and if you put the number 30000 the response should the number of pi, however it's not working here's the summation and here's the code.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>   
#include <limits.h> 
#include <ctype.h>  
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( void ){

int num, k;
double pi= 0;

printf("Digite o total de termos >=30000: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
if (num < 30000){
    printf("Erro.");
    
}else {
    for (k = 1; k<= num; k++){
        if (k % 2 == 0){
            pi = (double)(-1)/ (2*k -1);
            
            
        }else{
            pi =  (double)(1)/ (2*k -1);
        
           
        }
        pi = pi * 4;
    }
   
    printf("O valor de pi e %f", pi);
    
    
}



return 0; }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't perform any summation at all, though. There are no addition operations applied to `pi`.

Comment: Can you write down (pen and paper) the formula for n=3? I ask to clarify whether the meaning of the math representation is clear to you. If you can, then please also write down the formula for n=4. If you see those two formulas and assume that the result for n=3 is in a variable, do you see what you would need to do to get result for n=4 into that variable? I ask to clarify how much you know about using variables and operators.

Comment: Also drop _all_ integer constants. You should only be using floating point, that is `1.0` not `1`,  `2.0` not `2` and so on.

Comment: You ask specifically about doing this without math.c. Can I assume that you know how to do it with that lib? I ask because I do not see how it would become easier to do a summation like that with the lib. Or would you just use the constant provided by that lib? Then only the phrasing of the title confused me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general way to sum things up:

```
double sum(int from, int to, double (*f)(int)) {
    double ret = 0.0;

    for(int i=from; i<to; i++)
        ret+=f(i);

    return ret;
}
```

And then you can write this function:

```
double fun(int current) {
    double sign = current %2 == 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    return sign / (2*current - 1)
}
```

Finally, call it like this:

```
double pi = sum(1, num, fun);
```

Do note that this is probably not a good way to go if you're a beginner student that is looking for a solution to some homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double pi=0;
    
    for(int k=1; k<=3000; ++k)
    {
        pi += (2.*(k%2)-1) / (2*k-1);   // This line does a summation, and uses floating point math (Not Integer Math)
    }
    
    printf("Pi : %f\n", 4*pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.